# What does TruCoin do?

Tags: trucoin, gavin-andresen

I just saw that Gavin is employed with a company called [TruCoin](http://www.trucoin.com/). Any idea what does it actually do besides help develop and QA the bitcoin client?

The [about page](http://www.trucoin.com/?page_id=8) (odd URL) doesn't explain it much.

Answer (score 6):

From reading publicly available information it seems the intention of TruCoin is to create a set of stable business fronts that can benefit both the growth of bitcoin and also the company (ofcourse)

As we all know without stable business there will be very little growth. Working in close colaboration with the lead developer of bitcoin gives both a good understand of how to support the specific business metrics that bitcoin may demand when running a live and large e-commerce site.

Other upcoming sites may greatly benefit from any situations that they face and can certainly "test the water" for large organizations to use BTC.

Comment: Most of this is opinion and perception but hopefully some find it valid

Answer (score 1):

Right after posting this question I saw they're the one behind [Bitcoin Deals](http://www.bitcoindeals.com/) (selling items for bitcoins).

Comment: And that's about all we know about them right now.

Answer (score 1):

One service they offer is to provide an exit node for BitcoinJS (e.g., WebCoin )
 - https://exit.trucoin.com:3125/